# Why the method that we use to solve inequality problems with one absolute value does not work with two absolute values?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I would like to highlight that I am aware that there are different approaches to solving absolute value inequalities. However, I am interested in why this particular method, that I often use for single absolute value problems, does not work for those with two absolute values.

So for solving the most simple inequality problems like this one:

|x|≥3

I would divide it into two cases:

Case 1:

The initial domain are all positive numbers and 0.

x≥3

Case 2:

The initial domain are all negative numbers and 0

x≤-3

Then, I would find the union of the two solutions, to obtain the solution below:
x∈ ]-∞,-3] ∪[3,∞[

On the other hand, when applying this method for a problem with two absolute values it does not work well.

Let's consider this problem:

|2x+1|≥|x-2|

First, I would calculate the domains:

If we consider 2x+1>0, then x>-0.5

If we consider 2x+1<0, then x<-0.5

If we consider x-2>0, then x>2

If we consider x-2<0, then X<2

Thus, next I will take into account all the cases:

Case 1 - both sides positive - domain of x is x>-0.5;
 then I perform the calculations;
2x+1≥x-2;
x>-3;
The part in the domain is: [-0.5, ∞[

Case 2 - left side negative, right side positive - domain ]-∞,-0.5] ∪[2,∞[;
Now the left side is negative, so I put a - sign before the first function.
-2x-1>x-2;
x<0.333;
The part in the domain is: ]-∞,-0.5]

Case 3 - left side positive, right side negative - domain [-0.5, 2];
Now I consider the negative side for the other value:
2x+1>-x+2;
3x>1;
x>0.333;
The part in the domain: [0.333, 2]

Case 4 - both sides negative - domain ]-∞,2];
-2x-1>-x+2;
x<-3;
The part in the domain: ]-∞,-3]

Then analogically I take the union of all the solutions that fit in their domains.
I obtain the following result: x∈ ]-∞,2]

In reality the result should be the following: x∈ ]-∞,-3] ∪[0.333,∞[

I really do not know where I have done a mistake, as the approach is analogous to the one for the simpler example. If anyone would show me any mistakes or false assumptions that I have made, I would be very thankful. Btw, I know the approaches with squaring both sides and dividing the inequality into 3 sections according to their x-intercepts.

This is my first post, so I would also be up for any feedback that you guys could give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method does work, but you made some mistakes:

> Case 1 - both sides positive - domain of x is x>-0.5

That's not really the case.

$$ 2x + 1 > 0 \land x - 2 > 0 \iff x > 2 $$

So for Case 1 the domain is $ x > 2 $

For Case 2 domain is empty:

$$ 2x + 1 < 0 \land x - 2 > 0 \iff x \in \emptyset $$

You should continue your calculations for the domain of each case similarly. In fact, you should notice that the cases cover the whole $ \mathbb{R} $ completely and their intersections are empty (each point is covered only by one case). (Edit: this paragraph is true for at least as long, as each term to which absolute value is applied is a linear.)

For each case you should calculate the solution and take it's intersection with the domain, as you have noted.

> This is my first post, so I would also be up for any feedback that you guys could give me.

Use TeX to format your posts, they would be much nicer to read. It's also a useful skill for any mathematician or STEM student. To use TeX formatting on StackExchange type something like `$ x > 2 $` which will render as $ x > 2 $. For separate, centered formulas use `$$ x \in \emptyset $$` which will render as: $$ x \in \emptyset $$

I hope you find this answer useful. Just redo your calculations being a little bit more careful and good luck :)

Comment: Thank you very much! That was it!

Thanks for the tip about the formatting. I will learn it and try applying it in the future posts.